# How do you pull an item out of an overlay div?

Tags: html, css, sass

I need help. I created a `div` to overlay the background image. Then I nested another `div` with children `span` in it. I'd like to pull out those span selectors on the lines so they're not obscured by their overlay. I've already used `z-index` property on higher than overlay itself, but still all spans are hidden behind overlay. Maybe one of you can tell me what I'm doing wrong.

```css
.breadcrumbs {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: left;
    height: 100%;
    align-items: center;
    position: relative;
}

.breadcrumbs span {
    font-size: 1.6rem;
    color: white;
    font-weight: 900;
    font-style: italic;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10000;
}
.jumbotron {
    min-height: 550px;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    position: relative;
}
.overlay {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: black;
    opacity: 0.66;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

```html
<div class="jumbotron" style="background-image: url('...');">
    <div class="overlay">
        <div class="breadcrumbs">
            <span property="itemListElement" typeof="ListItem">
                <a property="item" typeof="WebPage" title="..." href="..." class="post-root post post-post">
                    <span property="name">News Page</span>
                </a>
                <meta property="position" content="2">
          </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Its usually helpful if you provide a link to jsfiddle or codepen with the issue to make it easier for people to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `spans` are hidden. If you mean that it gets opacity of the parent than you have to rearange your structure.. Your spans must be outside of the `.overlay`... maybe in next "main" container placed next to `.overlay` as `absolute` element placed on top of it

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be solved by removing opacity for `div` with `.overlay` class, then changing the property `background-color: black;` to e.g. `background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.336);`.